# how to change the session scope in php?

Tags: php, web-applications, session

i am using php to develop web applications. i used session to pass information from one page to other page. but the session is reset when it comes to other page. i think it is due to wrong scope of sessions(page scope)! am i correct? if it is the problem, then how to overcome the problem? please help me. thanks in advance!

Comment: are you using session_start() at the top of every page? I don't think $_SESSION really has a scope as it accessible everywhere once a session is started. Read this, it should help you out http://uk2.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php

Comment: Please check if you’re using the same session on both pages by comparing the session’s ID (see [`session_id`](http://php.net/session_id)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put `session_start()` at the beginning of every page - this will start a new session, or, in your case **resume a stored session**, along with it's variables. This will work unless you call `session_destroy()` before navigating to the new page.

Hope this helps,

James

Comment: @dimitris mistriotis - A nice idea, but a whole framework just for `session_id()`? Also, it's easy enough to just use `session_start()` - a large framework would be overkill for this specific application I reckon. It would be very handy if you wanted a whole load of functionality, however.

Comment: You're right... Just for one thing is not a sufficient reason

Comment: Thanks :-) Frameworks are an invaluable tool, but not for a single function ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Session doesn't have a scope,may be you are calling `session_destroy()` some where in your code